# Show/Hide Data if customer is logged/not logged in Magento

Tags: magento, helper

i need to Show and Hide one form is customer is or not logged in.

I have this helper:

```
    <?php
    if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ) {
        echo "Hide Form";
    } else {
        echo "<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="post.php">
<input name="Type your name" type="text" value="name" />
<label>
  <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Submit" />
</label>
</form>"; 
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php
    if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ) {
        $showHide = "style=display:none";
    } else { 
        $showHide = "style=display:block";
    }?>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="post.php" <?php echo $showHide;?> >
        <input name="Type your name" type="text" value="name" />
        <label>
            <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Submit" />
        </label>
    </form>
```

Comment: Its not good way to hide the form just by just doing display:none for logged out user. One like me can inspect element and make the form visible

Comment: I agree with @rajatsaurastri - the form should not be generated if the user is not logged in, as per the OP's requirements. It could also cause errors if the form is expecting the logged-in user's ID, for example.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your problem is coming from the quotes in the html you are echoing.  Php sees that chunk as `echo "<form id="` followed by a bunch of gibberish it doesn't know what to do with.

The solution depends on where that chunk of code is.  If it is in a template(.phtml) file then Kalpesh Mehta's method will work.

If it is in something like a block, helper, or controller, their solution wont work.  The easiest solution in that case would be to change the two outside double quotes(") to single quotes(').

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this option in review file .phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideshow(which){
if (!document.getElementById)
return
if (which.style.display=="block")
which.style.display="none"
else
which.style.display="block"
}
</script>
<?php
    if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ) {
        $showHide = "style=display:none";
    } else { 
        $showHide = "style=display:block";
    }?>
<?php if(Mage::helper('oscheckout')->isCouponActive()):?>
<div class="fivecol" id="coupon-container">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
</div>
```